# Why do I get "No transports initialized" error when starting JBoss with remote debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, jboss, remote-debugging

I've modified my run.sh file and added `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n"` but when I start JBoss I get  `FATAL ERROR in native method: No transports initialized`.

Looking around the internet it seems like it may having something to do with missing jars or my version of Java?  I'm on J2SDK JRE 1.4.2.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can mean many things but for me, this error meant there was already a process listening on port 1044.  All I had to do was change my port address to 1045 and problem was solved.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1045,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, I fixed it by changing my `JAVA_OPTS` from this:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=n,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

To this:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error like the following:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: No transports initialized
err:: No such file or directory
Error [2] in connect() call!
Socket transport failed to init.
Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, rc = -1.
```

I resolve it by changing the start timeout limit.

http://stanicblog.blogspot.sg/2013/11/eclipse-tomcat-unable-to-start-within.html